# "Invalid Class" Error while Starting FTp Site in IIS 7.0 using WMI and ASP.Net C# (windows Server 2008)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, ftp, wmi

I am working on an ASP.Net Web Site Provisioning software using WMI(System.Managment) and C#.

**I am trying to create FTP site on my "Target Server" located somewhere on LAN while executing code on my host machine. I have trouble starting the FTP Site after its creations.**

The error being reported is **"Invalid Class"** on the following line:

```
ManagementObject site = new ManagementObject(
          new ManagementPath(string.Format(@"IIsFtpServer.Name='MSFTPSVC/{0}'", siteId)), null);
        **site.InvokeMethod("Start", null);**
```

Here is my Complete Function.

```
public static String CreateFtpsite(String serverName,
    String ip,String ServerComment,int AccessFlags,
    String pathToRoot, String hostName, String domainName, int port)
{
    //ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    //options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Connect;
    //options.EnablePrivileges = true;
    //options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    ConnectionOptions options = SetUpAuthorization();
    ManagementScope scope =
       new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\MicrosoftIISv2", serverName), options);
    scope.Connect();
    ManagementObject oW3SVC = new ManagementObject(scope,
    new ManagementPath(@"IIsFtpService='MSFTPSVC'"), null);

    ManagementBaseObject[] serverBindings = new ManagementBaseObject[3];
    /*serverBindings[0] = CreateServerBinding(scope, 
                        string.Format("{0}.{1}", hostName, domainName), ip, port);
    */
    serverBindings[0] = CreateServerBinding(scope,
                        string.Format("{0}", hostName, domainName), ip, port);
    serverBindings[1] = CreateServerBinding(scope,
                        string.Format(ip, hostName, domainName), ip, port);
    serverBindings[2] = CreateServerBinding(scope,
                        string.Format("127.0.0.1", hostName, domainName), ip, port);

    ManagementBaseObject inputParameters = oW3SVC.GetMethodParameters("CreateNewSite");

    inputParameters["ServerBindings"] = serverBindings;
    inputParameters["ServerComment"] = ServerComment;
    inputParameters["PathOfRootVirtualDir"] = pathToRoot;

    ManagementBaseObject outParameter =
      oW3SVC.InvokeMethod("CreateNewSite", inputParameters, null);

    string siteId = Convert.ToString(
     outParameter.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value).Replace(
     "IIsFtpServer='MSFTPSVC/", "").Replace("'", "");
    ManagementObject oFtpVirtDir = new ManagementObject(scope,
    new ManagementPath(string.Format(
        @"IIsFtpVirtualDirSetting.Name='MSFTPSVC/{0}/root'", siteId)), null);
    oFtpVirtDir.Properties["AccessFlags"].Value = AccessFlags ;
    oFtpVirtDir.Properties["Path"].Value = pathToRoot;

    ManagementObject oFtpVirtDirProperties = new ManagementObject(scope,
    new ManagementPath(string.Format(@"IIsFtpServerSetting.Name='MSFTPSVC/{0}'", siteId)), null);
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["AllowAnonymous"].Value  = true;
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["AnonymousOnly"].Value = true;
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["AnonymousUserName"].Value = @"DevIIS\Administrator";
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["AnonymousUserPass"].Value = "Passw0rd";
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["MaxConnections"].Value = 555;
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["ServerAutoStart"].Value = true;
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["UserIsolationMode"].Value = 1;
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["ConnectionTimeout"].Value = 1234 ;
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Properties["LogFileTruncateSize"].Value = 54321;
    oFtpVirtDirProperties.Put();

    ManagementObject site = new ManagementObject(
      new ManagementPath(string.Format(@"IIsFtpServer.Name='MSFTPSVC/{0}'", siteId)), null);
    site.InvokeMethod("Start", null); //Error occurs Here (Invalid Class)
    return siteId;
}

public static ConnectionOptions SetUpAuthorization()
    {
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

        options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
        options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        options.Username = @"DevIIS\Administrator";
        options.Password = "Passw0rd";
        return options;
    }
```

On analyzing the Code, i find that the "site" object throws exception of "Invalid Class" on `"site.ClassPath".`

I have also tried to use the following line but the same error is there.

```
ManagementObject site = new ManagementObject(scope, 
      new ManagementPath(Convert.ToString(
      outParameter.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value)), null);

        site.InvokeMethod("Start", null);
```

But the FTP Site is created and all its properties are set but it doesn't start via code. One may manually start it by going to IIS Manager .

**The Code works perfectly fine on IIS 6.0 and (since i am using using WMI ) i expect that it should run fine on IIS 7.0 or later too.**

I am doing something wrong but couldn't guess where. Kindly help. Thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iis7 it does not create "MSFTPSVC" folder in the metabase. it places ftpsite in the website container in the database. so the answer will be :
use @"IIsWebService='W3SVC'" as a management path, instead of what you are using.

Comment: I figured the problem myself as i was calling the function on the wrong class. The "Start" method has to be called on the server class.  i.e IIsWebServer.Start() or IIsFtpServer.Start()

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem myself as i was calling the function on the wrong class. The "Start" method has to be called on the server class. i.e IIsWebServer.Start() or IIsFtpServer.Start()